# Static Analyser Warning on returned doubles?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am getting a warning from the Xcode 3.2.5 static analyser that I don't quite understand, the warning is:

> Warning: The receiver of message
>   'horizontalAccuracy' is nil and
>   returns a value of type
>   'CLLocationAccuracy' that will be
>   garbage
>                        if([lastGoodLocation
>   horizontalAccuracy] <=
>   DESIREDACCURACY) {

The code compiles and runs fine, but I am just curious as to what is happening and how I might fix it.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) CLLocation *lastGoodLocation;

@synthesize lastGoodLocation;
```

.

```
// CHECK FOR BEST LOCATION
if(lastGoodLocation == nil || [newLocation horizontalAccuracy] < [lastGoodLocation horizontalAccuracy]) {
    NSLog(@"NEWBEST: %0.0fm (%@)", [newLocation horizontalAccuracy], [newLocation timestamp]);
    [self setLastGoodLocation:newLocation];

    // DESIRED ACCURACY & GEOCODE
    if([lastGoodLocation horizontalAccuracy] <= DESIREDACCURACY) {
```

## EDIT:

Can newLocation be returned as nil, this code is in:

`locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get into the outer `if` when `lastGoodLocation` is nil (left-hand side of the `||` condition), and within that `if` block, you're calling `[lastGoodLocation horizontalAccuracy]` on a possibly nil reference.  Change the inner `if` to something like

```
// DESIRED ACCURACY & GEOCODE
if (lastGoodLocation != nil && ([lastGoodLocation horizontalAccuracy] <= DESIREDACCURACY))
```

It may be that `#setLastGoodLocation` actually sets `lastGoodLocation`, but the analyzer may not spot that.

**EDIT:**

The docs at [developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/CLLocationManagerDelegate/CLLocationManagerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/CLLocationManagerDelegate/locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:) suggest that while oldLocation may be nil (on the first fix), newLocation probably shouldn't be -- if location isn't working, I think you'd receive `#locationManager:didFailWithError:` instead.

Comment: ... but what if newLocation is nil, too.  The inner calll to horizontalAccuracy should have a test-for-nil.

Comment: Much appreciated, I am pretty sure the code is ok and like you say its the analyser missing the "setLastGoodLocation", for now I have added "lastGoodLocation != nil" which removes the warning. I will look at refactoring the code later and see if I can tighten things up a little more.

Comment: @bbum: I think the static analyser message is spurious.  If you look at this document, sending a message that returns double to nil is clearly defined to return 0. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocObjectsClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH11-SW7 If you agree with me, I'll submit a bug report to Apple.

Comment: It is a bug in the static analyzer because objc_msgSend_fpret() was added to handle the msg-to-nil-with-double-return-on-i386 case.  Forgot about that variant.

Comment: Just curious if I am missing the point, in my case it can't be nil can it, as it gets set to newLocation on the line before. The error is wrong as as returning double to nil should be 0. But in this case the analyser is also failing to see/understand [self setLastGoodLocation: newLocation];